# What is a good way to set local storage?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have made a high contrast mode but I have gotten stuck with trying to save the new value to local storage, any guidance I will be appreciated.

Here is the themes wrapper where I am setting up the theme

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ThemeContext, themes } from '../context/themeContext';

export function isOdd(num) { 
  
  console.log("isOdd",num % 2);
}

export default function ThemeContextWrapper(props) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(themes.dark);

  function changeTheme(theme) {
    setTheme(theme);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (theme) {
      case themes.light:
        document.body.classList.add('white-content');
         // Store
  // Retrieve
        break;
      case themes.dark:
      default:
        document.body.classList.remove('white-content');
        localStorage.setItem(theme, themes.dark);
          localStorage.getItem(theme);



        break;
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: theme, changeTheme: changeTheme }}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

and here is the on click listener that triggers the high contrast mode

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import 'devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css';
import 'devextreme/dist/css/dx.material.blue.light.css';
// Custom icons by Ionicons
import 'ionicons/dist/css/ionicons.css';
import DarkModeicon from '../images/icons/dark-mode-icon.png'
import SpeedDialAction from 'devextreme-react/speed-dial-action';
import { isOdd } from '../themewrapper/themeWrapperContext';
import Sun from '../images/icons/sun.png'

import config from 'devextreme/core/config';
import notify from 'devextreme/ui/notify';
import '../App.css';


class FloatingActionButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      

    

        config({
            floatingActionButtonConfig: {
                icon: 'runner',
                closeIcon: 'icon ion-md-close',
                position: {
                    my: 'right bottom',
                    at: 'right bottom',
                    offset: '-16 -16'
                }
            }
        });
    }
    

  

  
//   function enabled night mode
    toggleTheme() {
        isOdd(3)
        console.log("toggleTheme click func")

        document.body.classList.add('dark-content');
        localStorage.setItem(theme, themes.dark);
        localStorage.getItem(theme, themes.dark);


    }
         

        

    
    toggleDay() {
        isOdd(3)
        console.log("toggle day click func")

        document.body.classList.remove('dark-content');
        document.body.classList.add('white-content');

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div id="app-container">
                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="Turn on Day Mode"
                    icon={Sun}
                    onClick={() => this.toggleDay()}
                />
             
             <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="Increase Font"
                    icon="growfont"
                    onClick={() =>
                        alert("Increase Font Clicked!!")
                    }
                />
                <SpeedDialAction
                    hint="turn on night mode"
                    icon={DarkModeicon}
                    onClick={() => this.toggleTheme()}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default FloatingActionButton;
```

I tried to set up the local storage in both the on click listener and theme wrapper no success.

Comment: When you get data from localStorage you need to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

As using the `Context.Provider' to provide the value to the child, you should also use` Context.Consumer' in the child which needs to pick the value from provider.

So in `FloatingActionButton` component, you might use this instead:

```
class FloatingActionButton extends React.Component {
  // ...some other code

  toggleTheme(theme, changeTheme) {
    let newTheme;
    if (theme === themes.light) {
      newTheme = themes.dark;
    } else {
      newTheme = themes.light;
    }
    changeTheme(newTheme); // set the theme immediately
    localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme); // then save it into localStorage
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(theme, changeTheme) => (
          // ...some other elements
          <button onClick={() => toggleTheme(theme, changeTheme)}>
            Toggle Theme
          </button>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

Then you can detect the theme in the `ThemeContextWrapper` component:

```
export default function ThemeContextWrapper(props) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(); // keep the default value as null because it will get the value in localStorage when useEffect detect the first render.

  function changeTheme(theme) {
    setTheme(theme);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (theme) {
      case themes.light:
        document.body.classList.add('white-content');
        break;
      case themes.dark:
        document.body.classList.remove('white-content');
      default:
        const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
        if (savedTheme) {
          setTheme(savedTheme)
        } else { // if there is no theme data in localStorage, set theme to dark mode
          setTheme(themes.dark)
        }
        break;
    }
  }, [theme]);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme: theme, changeTheme: changeTheme }}>
      {props.children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```